# Change Hosts 1.1.0 not working

Tags: 12.04, hosts, firefox-extensions

I installed this addon Change Hosts 1.1.0 in firefox, and saved my preferences for hosts file in it. But when i select any host configuration from the addon it throws an error citing unable to save the configuration. What shall i do?

Moreover, out of all the definitions, atleast one has to be selected. What if i want to select none out of them? How can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out :), had to change the hosts file permissions by executing the following:-

```
sudo chown user:localohost hosts
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer

Comment: Moreover, out of all the definitions, atleast one has to be selected. What if i want to select none out of them? How can i do that??

Comment: Stab in the dark: Try ctrl+click?

Comment: ctrl+click doesn't work...